# Using checkbox to show nav (content) doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, css

I have the following setup (view in a narrow window, <750px wide): http://codepen.io/darrylhein/pen/oFalc

The problem is that the hide/show of the navigation doesn't work in Android's default browser. It seems to work pretty much everywhere else. (It does work in Firefox on Android.)

Basically I'm using `input:checked ~ .class { height: 16em; }` to show the nav.

I've tried removing the transition and a variety of other things and it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

I'd like to avoid using JS, but if I have to I will.

Answer (score 0):

So, 2 parts to the solution:

1) The problem occurs on Android <4.1.2. The solution is to add a fake animation on the body:

```
body { -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s; }
@-webkit-keyframes bugfix { 
    from { padding:0; }
    to { padding:0; }
}
```

2) There is also a problem on iOS <6 where labels do not check checkbox. The solution is to add an `onclick` to the `label`:

```
<label for="checkbox" onclick>Menu</label>
```

I found the solutions here: http://timpietrusky.com/advanced-checkbox-hack

I've also updated the codepen: http://codepen.io/darrylhein/pen/oFalc